# Sinatra: Rack::Session::Cookie expiration date ignored

Tags: sinatra, rack

Following the instructions from [How do I use sessions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions) from the sinatra FAQ, I am creating session cookies like so:

```
  use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
                             :path => '/',
                             :expire_after => 315_360_000, # In seconds
                             :secret => 'my secret'
```

However, when I check the cookie being set, it's expiration is set to the end of the browser session.  What step am I missing to make the expiration date I set work?

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Did you solve it?

Comment: I believe the problem was that I was using sinatra sessions via `enable :sessions` and `Rack::Session::Cookie` simultaneously.  So make sure you're using only the latter.  I just created a simple test app using only `Rack::Session::Cookie` and it works fine (ie, does not delete the cookie upon browser close)